# One div block above another

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a mini gallery grid with three elements like these:

```
-----------------------      -----------------------
-                     -      -                     -
-                     -      -                     -
-                     -      -       element 2     -
-     element 1       -      -                     -
-                     -      -                     -
-                     -      -----------------------
-                     -      -----------------------
-                     -      -                     -
-                     -      -                     -  
-                     -      -    element3         -   
-                     -      -                     -
-                     -      -                     -
-                     -      -                     -
- - - - - - - - - - - -      -----------------------
```

All these three elements are in a CSS class named `.gallery`, and `element 2` and `element 3` are in the CSS class named `.small`.

I have tried to make is alone but I will use the script on a mobile website. My code is working but when I resize the browser window the elements 2 and 3 are floating left.

CSS:

```
.gallery li{
  background: #ccc;
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1%;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.gallery .big{
  height: 205px;
  width:48%;
}

.gallery .small{
  height:100px;
  width: 48%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <li class="big"></li>
  <li class="small"></li>
  <li class="small"></li>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is working.https://jsfiddle.net/ntr245nq/

Comment: Yes its working perfect. please mention your desired output while on small screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not experiencing this issue with the following altered CSS.

```
.gallery li{ 
    background: #ccc;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1%;
    list-style: none;
}

.gallery .big {
    height: 205px;
    width:48%;
    float: left;
}

.gallery .small{
    height:100px;
    width: 48%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I have what you wanted. It was a simple fix of changing the margins. You may want to play with it a bit more. I would also recommend that instead of having just the width re-size to the veiwport, I would have the height do the same, in an aspect ratio which looks good to you.

Html:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <li class="big"></li>
  <li class="small"></li>
  <li class="small"></li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .gallery li{
background: #ccc;
width:100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 1%;
list-style: none;
float: left;
}

.gallery .big{
height: 220px;
width:48%;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

.gallery .small{
height:100px;
width: 48%;
margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are asking now, and the answer you selected does it well. glad I was able to help in some way I guess.

Comment: By your script by small sizes the div are one above the other and i will one left the other (about the sketch above) Michael scripts work, but i will make that element1 the same size with 2 and 3  permanently to be, how can i make these?

Comment: Taking from the answer you selected I made this: https://jsfiddle.net/jcncL8bx/6/
its not perfect, and to see the results the best I recommend you go to:https://jsfiddle.net/jcncL8bx/6/embedded/result/#Result